# Can't get users from roster (Smack)

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I'm using `Smack` and `xmpp` for sending messages, I created two users in the server `OpenFire`, created group Friends and added both users on the group.

[image]

Now I want to get users from the roster on my phone, I'm using such code for that:

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
Presence presence;
for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
    presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
    Log.e("Users in roster ", entry.getUser());
    Log.e("Name of user in roster ", presence.getType().name());
    Log.e("Status in roster", presence.getStatus());
}
```

I get `entries` size zero, so I didn't see in the the log name of the users from roster. Why size of the `entries` is zero? How to get users from roster? What I'm doing wrong? 
Both users are online. I can send and get messages from one user to another (so problems with the connection can be excluded).

Also I want to add, that when I check roster in OpenFire, I see user in the roster there:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.iryna.smack"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.4'
// Optional for XMPPTCPConnection
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.4'
// Optional for XMPP-IM (RFC 6121) support (Roster, Threaded Chats)
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.4'
// Optional for XMPP extensions support
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: pest your build.gradle (Module:app)

Comment: Openfire groups are not Roster groups, they are a custom feature of Openfire.

Comment: @Radhey just have added it.

Comment: @MrPk How to create Rosters in that case?

Comment: put ,  if (!roster.isLoaded())
    try {
        roster.reloadAndWait();
    } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException | SmackException.NotConnectedException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } , statements before your for loop .@Lucky_girl

Comment: @Radhey  I just have tried it, result is still the same.

Comment: anybody got this working?

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing this problem...